# откат Windows 10 без потери данных

Tags: windows, windows-10

День добрый!

Вопрос вот в чем:
Есть два аккаунта, А и Б, мне нужно вернуться к исходное состояние виндовс, что бы все файлы, которые используются на аккаунте А не были затронуты, а на аккаунте Б было все очищено.

Такое возможно?

Answer (score 1):

1. Делаете [восстановление с сохранением пользовательских данных](http://remontka.pro/windows-10-recovery/):

Параметры --> Обновление и безопасность --> Восстановление --> Вернуть компьютер в исходное состояние --> Начать

2. Удаляете профиль пользователя Б:

Панель управления --> Система --> Дополнительные параметры системы -->  Профили пользователей --> Параметры... --> Выделяете пользователя Б --> Удалить